# Solving coupled Differential Equation by Matlab or by calculations

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

Solving coupled non linear differential equation by  Mat-lab or  by calculations

```
equation 1:   x'(t) = -a* x(t) /(x(t) + y(t))
equation 2:   y'(t) = -b* y(t) /(x(t) + y(t))
```

I tried in [mathematica](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=DSolve%5B%7Bx%27%5Bt%5D%20==%20-a%2ax%5Bt%5D%20/%28x%5Bt%5D%2by%5Bt%5D%29,%20y%27%5Bt%5D%20==%20-b%2ay%5Bt%5D%20/%28x%5Bt%5D%2by%5Bt%5D%29%7D,%20%7Bx,%20y%7D,%20t%5D) but got a very comlicated solution.

```
Solve[{x'[t] == -a* x[t] /(x[t] + y[t]), y'[t] == -b* y[t] /(x[t] + y[t])}, {x, y}, t]
```

How can I plot it?

My initial conditions are

```
 x(0) = xo
 y(0) = yo
```

Also, a and b are constants.

I have to plot x and y wrt t after inserting values of  a and b . ( a= 2 , b =5 say )

Answer (score 6):

A lot of things to note in this situation:

1. You need to create a function that contains both a and b:

   ```
   function dy =soProblem(t,y,a,b)
       dy=[-a*y(1)/(y(1)+y(2)); -b*y(2)/(y(1)+y(2))];
   end
   ```
2. Call the standard ode function:

   ```
   a = 2;
   b = 5; tend = 10; x0 = 1; y0 = 2;
   [T,Y] = ode45(@(t,y)soProblem(t,y,a,b),[0 tend],[x0 y0]);
   plot (T,Y)
   ```
3. Realize you may have a [stiff equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiff_equation) on your hands.
4. Have fun identifying the ideal function call:

   ```
   [T15,Y15] = ode15s(@(t,y)soProblem(t,y,a,b),[0 tend],[x0 y0]);
   [T23t,Y23t] = ode23t(@(t,y)soProblem(t,y,a,b),[0 tend],[x0 y0]);
   [T23tb,Y23tb] = ode23tb(@(t,y)soProblem(t,y,a,b),[0 tend],[x0 y0]);
   %note ode23s doesn't converge (or at least takes forever)
   plot (T,Y,T15,Y15,T23t,Y23t,T23tb,Y23tb)
   ```
5. Understand why mathematica becomes restless

Answer (score 0):

In mathematica:
    Try ndsolve

In matlab:

Create a function file yourfunction.m:

```
function [Y_prime]=yourfunction(t, Y)
    Y_prime=[-2*Y(1)./(Y(1) + Y(2)) -5*Y(2)./(Y(1) + Y(2))];
end
```

and then

```
[T,Y] = ode45(yourfunction,[0 t_end],[x0 y0]);
plot(T,Y(:,1));
hold on
plot(T,Y(:,2));
```